# BigQuery - sum arrays and exclude part of array

Tags: google-bigquery

Just getting started with `BigQuery` so I apologise in advance if this question is stupid >_<

I have a record with multi-value fields which looks like this, and the value each delimited position relates to the same position in the adjacent field:
[record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUli3.png)

What I'm hoping to do is to sum the amounts which are red, e.g.
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAL12.png)

Have tried messing around with `CROSS JOIN`s on `UNNEST`, `STRING`, but generally I either receive a *Scaler subquery produced more than one element* error, or my sum just gets duplicated somehow.

While my oracle SQL skills can easily manage multi-value fields, I'm really struggling here with BigQuery - Please send help!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `amount` and `color` fields are strings (as opposed to Arrays), let's start with some sample data.

```
WITH tbl AS (
  SELECT 1 id, '25,17,20' amount, 'red,blue,red' color UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '10,20,30,40', 'green,brown,brown,red'
)
```

The goal is to take the sum of `amount`, grouped by `id` and `color`.

You were on the right track with `UNNEST`, but you need to use `OFFSET` to keep track of values in matching positions.

```
SELECT id, split_color, SUM(CAST(split_amount AS INT64)) amount_sum, 
FROM tbl,
UNNEST(SPLIT(amount)) split_amount WITH OFFSET idx_amount,
UNNEST(SPLIT(color)) split_color WITH OFFSET idx_color
WHERE 
  idx_amount = idx_color AND
  split_color = 'red'
GROUP BY id, split_color;
```

Note that if your data are stored as Arrays, then you won't need to use `SPLIT` (and you probably won't need to cast to numeric to sum either).

Comment: Thanks heaps @user45392 yeah the data I was working with wasn't stored as an array, which was causing me some issues. I finally managed to find the same data in an array I could unnest easily and managed to get that working. But knowing the database I'm working with I'll come up against this again undoubtedly

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  id, 
  'red' AS colour,
  ( SELECT SUM(CAST(num AS INT64))
    FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(amount)) AS num WITH OFFSET
    JOIN UNNEST(SPLIT(colour)) AS col WITH OFFSET
    USING(OFFSET)
    WHERE col = 'red'
  ) AS sum_amount
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```